# Is performance hit hard when you reinitialize a subscription in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I haven't worked with reinitializing a subscription for SQL Server 2005 replication before and the time has come. I've added a few new articles and need to push those down to the subscriber. Before I reinitialize, which I've read is what I want to do, I want to have a feel for potential performance hit when I kick it off. My gut says that all should be fine but I'd appreciate any experience you have.

The goods:
-Publishing db server is big, fast, with loads of RAM and running enterprise.
-The subscription covers numerous tables with good amounts of data (30 GB) but the new articles are super small.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW - There was not a performance hit.